# VBA Creating Sheets, error handeling

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using the code below, to copy a hidden worksheet and copy it, rename is and fill in certain fields on two sheets.

I have done it like this, as i need to copy the layout and formatting of the hidden sheet.

The problem I am having, is that when i click the create button, if the sheet already exits, it completely crashes Excel, I have tried to add error handling but everything i have tried to check if the sheet exists doesn't work and still crashes Excel.

Have have separated the code that is un-hides the template sheet, copys it, renames the new sheet, and then re-hides the template.

What I would like it to do, is check the entered sheet name from TextBox5, and check is the sheet exists, if it does the display a message box, saying sheet already exists, if the sheet does not exist them carry on with the code as normal.

If really appreciate all the help and support i have already received, and thank all of you for the help you can provide with this.

```
   Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
        Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Template")
        Dim newws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, newname
        Dim query As Long, xst As Boolean, info As String
        Dim NextRow As Long, myCCName As Variant, lastRow2 As Long, lastRow As Long
        'Contract Name
        Dim Contact As String, name As String, name2 As String, SpacePos As Integer
        Dim answer As Integer
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    lastRow2 = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("A18:A34").End(xlDown).Row
    lastRow = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).Row

    'Contract Name
    Set contract = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9")
    SpacePos = InStr(contract, "- ")
    name = Left(contract, SpacePos)
    name2 = Right(contract, Len(contract) - Len(name))
    '
    retry:
        xst = False
        newname = Me.TextBox5.Value
        myCCName = Me.TextBox4.Value
        If newname = "" Then
            MsgBox "You have not entered a CC Code Number. Please enter CC Code Number!", vbExclamation, "An Error Occured"
        Exit Sub
        End If
        If myCCName = "" Then
            MsgBox "You have not entered a CC Code Name. Please enter CC Code Name!", vbExclamation, "An Error Occured"
        Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each sh In wb.Sheets
            If sh.name = newname Then
                xst = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then
            info = "Sheet name is invalid. Please retry."
            GoTo retry
        End If
```

> ```
> Sheets("Template").Visible = True
> ws.Copy before:=Sheets("Details"): Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.name = newname
> Sheets("Template").Visible = False
> ```

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Payment Form").Activate
    For Each cell In Columns(1).Range("A18:A34").Cells
         If Len(cell) = 0 Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell
    ActiveCell.Value = newname & " " & "-" & name2 & ":" & " " & myCCName
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(newname).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(newname).Range("D4") = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("a18:a34").End(xlDown).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(newname).Range("D6") = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("L11").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(newname).Range("D8") = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(newname).Range("D10") = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("C11").Value
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Payment Form").Activate

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Payment Form")
    Range("J" & lastRow2 + 1) = 0
    Range("L" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 + 1 & "-J" & lastRow2 + 1 & ""
    Range("N" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "='" & newname & "'!L20"
    Range("U" & lastRow + 1) = newname & ":" & " "
    Range("V" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & newname & "'!I21"
    Range("W" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & newname & "'!L23"
    Range("X" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & newname & "'!K21"
End With

answer = MsgBox("Would you like to create another sheet?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "New Sheet")

If answer = vbYes Then

Else
    Unload Me
End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = True
    End With

    Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be a few general typos and a few errors with your 'With' statements throughout the code.
I have hopefully tidied up and recoded the function to work, but as it is untested I can't guarantee it will work off the bat.

I have also included the worksheet check function as a separate function

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet: Set wsTemplate = wb.Sheets("Template")
    Dim wsPayment As Worksheet: Set wsPayment = wb.Sheets("Payment Form")
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    Dim NewName As String: NewName = Me.TextBox5.Value
    Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = Me.TextBox4.Value

    If NewName = "" Or CCName = "" Then
        MsgBox "CC Code Name or Number missing. Please check details!", vbExclamation, "An Error Occured"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If WorksheetExists(NewName) Then
        MsgBox "Sheet name already exists. Please retry!", vbExclamation, "An Error Occured"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = wsPayment.Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).Row
    Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = wsPayment.Range("A18:A34").End(xlDown).Row

    'Contract Name
    Dim Contract As String: Contract = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").Value
    Dim SpacePos As Integer: SpacePos = InStr(Contract, "- ")
    Dim Name As String: Name = Left(Contract, SpacePos)
    Dim Name2 As String: Name2 = Right(Contract, Len(Contract) - Len(Name))

    wsTemplate.Visible = True
    wsTemplate.Copy before:=Sheets("Details"): Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
    wsTemplate.Visible = False

    With wsPayment
        For Each Cell In .Range("A18:A34")
            If Len(Cell) = 0 Then
                Cell.Value = NewName & " -" & Name2 & ": " & CCName
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With

    With wsNew
        .Name = NewName
        .Range("D4").Value = wsPayment.Range("A18:A34").End(xlDown).Value
        .Range("D6").Value = wsPayment.Range("L11").Value
        .Range("D8").Value = wsPayment.Range("C9").Value
        .Range("D10").Value = wsPayment.Range("C11").Value
    End With

    With wsPayment
        .Range("J" & lastRow2 + 1).Value = 0
        .Range("L" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 + 1 & "-J" & lastRow2 + 1 & ""
        .Range("N" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!L20"
        .Range("U" & lastRow + 1).Value = NewName & ": "
        .Range("V" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!I21"
        .Range("W" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!L23"
        .Range("X" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!K21"
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = True
    End With

    Dim Answer As Integer: Answer = MsgBox("Would you like to create another sheet?", _
        vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "New Sheet")
    If Answer = vbNo Then Unload Me

    Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Flephal. That you so much!!!! This mas made the code more stable and it now runs even smoother! I really apprecaiet all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use the function below to check if a sheet allready exist in the workbook, in which case it returns True:

```
Public Function doItExist(strSheetName as String) As Boolean
    Dim wsTest As Worksheet: Set wsTest = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsTest Is Nothing Then
        doExist = False
    Else
        doExist = True
    End If

End Function
```

I cannot seem to find the original source for the code, but I cannot take credit, it is mearly a modified version of some code I found on either SO, ozgrid or Mrexcel

EDIT:

Taking a closer look at your code, it seems you allready check for the existence of the sheetname in the xst variable. As far as I can see the user is not able to update the sheetname if is invalid, as the retry block will just keep looping?

under retry:

```
'### This bit essentially does the same as doSheetExist
For Each sh In wb.Sheets
    If sh.name = newname Then
        xst = True: Exit For
    End If
Next
'###

If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then 'if you go for the doSheetExist, then the xst check is obsolete. Else move the xst check to the elseif and remove the doSheetExist call
    info = "Sheet name is invalid. Please retry."
    'GoTo retry 'As far as I can tell calling retry would just cause an infinite loop as the user have had no chance to update sheetname
    Exit Sub 'let the user update and click the button again
ElseIf doSheetExist(newname) = True Then
    info = "Sheet name allready exist. Please specify other sheetname"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Andreas N. Hi thanks for the support, how would i get this to run in the code im using?? thanks

Comment: Taking a closer look it seems you allready had a working check for the sheetname, but the 'GoTo retry' would just keep looping as the user would have had no chance to update newname